# "was called" vs. "has been called"

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

I know the basics about past tense vs present perfect tense, but I'm wondering in some situations whether the "connection to the present" (which seems to be a necessity for the present perfect tense) does indeed exist or not, e.g., in the following example from computer programming (where you can "call a function", i.e., execute it):

> 1. Only use function A if the function B was called before.
> 2. Only use function A if the function B has been called before.

What's the correct way? Is it different in American English vs. British English?

Comment: As a side note, there should be no article in front of *function B*.

Comment: Jason, I disagree with you. “... if the function B ...” suggests that function B has been previously defined and is already familiar to the reader.

Comment: As Jason says, you don't want *the*. I am a BrE speaker and have a strong preference for (2). I'm not sure I would include *before* though. I might put *has previously been called*, but it depends on the details. I believe that (1) would be at least as likely in AmE but that (2) is still correct.

Answer (score 1):

I feel both  be correct. Any grammatical subtleties of the difference have no effect whatsoever on the meaning or the practical outcome.

Comment: OK, sounds good. So what's more common? Are there usage differences due to American/British English? Norther/Southern style?